# How to test Ajax page redirection with capybara selenium driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I want to test my user registration page which is ajax form and the page will be redirected to same page with flash message. How can I test this with capybara & selenium, I tried with the below code and it is not working.

```
it "Registers new user" do
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    visit registrations_new_path
    fill_in "reg_email", :with => user.email
    fill_in "password", :with => user.password
    page.execute_script "$('.register-span').trigger('mouseenter').click();"
    page.should have_content("   We have send you an confirmation e-mail. Please click on the link in the e-mail to activate your account. If you didn’t receive any e-mail please check your spam fielder or click on resend. Resend e-mail ")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Got working after adding the wait time in spec_helper.rb

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
```